# Add the values of two arrays with different dimensions together

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm not sure if this is mathematically possible, but I'd figure I'd ask anyway.

I have two arrays with sizes `(50,1)` and `(693,1)`. What I want to do is add these values together each time. In other words, I want to take the values in the first array `(50,1)` and add it to each of the values in the array size `(693,1)`. Is there a way to do this in python? Every thing I've tried fails because of the different sizes of the arrays.

*EDIT*

Here's a short example of what I was thinking:

```
array_1 = [1,1,4,5]
array_2 = [1,3,4]

new_array = [2, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4, 7, 8, 5, 5, 8, 9]
```

So taking each of the elements in `array_2` and adding them to each element of `array_1`

Comment: Do you mean you want a 2D output with shape 693x50? Can you give an example with two short arrays?

Comment: Sure thing, just edited it to add an example. Does the example make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcast, sum, and flatten:

```
array_1 = np.array([1,1,4,5])
array_2 = np.array([1,3,4])

out = (array_1+array_2[:,None]).ravel()
```

Or:

```
out = np.add.outer(array_2, array_1).ravel()
```

output: `array([2, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4, 7, 8, 5, 5, 8, 9])`

Comment: Ah, that did the trick I think! Thanks!!